# Is editing a hashset in multiple tasks (at once?) thread-safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency, async-await

I have an application that has to create `RegistrationInput`s. Of every Input I'm turning into a `RegistrationInput` I save the ID in a hashset of integers to make sure I'm never processing the same Input more than once. I need to make the registrationinputs of my array of inputs asynchronously, but if I see during the creation of one of the `RegistrationInputs` that any of the values isn't correct, I return null and remove the ID from the hashset.

Is what I'm doing thread-safe? Also is this the best way to asynchronously process data? I already tried `Parallel.Foreach` with an `async` lambda but that returns `async` void so I can't await it.

```
Inputs[] events = GetInputs();
List<Task<RegistrationInput>> tasks = new List<Task<RegistrationInput>>();
foreach (var ev in events)
    tasks.Add(ProcessEvent(ev));

tempInputs = await Task.WhenAll<RegistrationInput>(tasks);
```

Comment: Your technique is right, but you'll need to synchronize any access to the HashSet.

Comment: So protect the HashSet with a lock statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is what I'm doing thread-safe?

No, a [`HashSet<T>` is not thread-safe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx). If you need to modify it from multiple threads, you'll need to use a `lock`:

> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are
>   thread safe. **Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread
>   safe.**

The best thing you could do is make those concurrent operations completely unaware of each other, and have some higher level mechanism that makes sure no two IDs are queried twice.

> Also is this the best way to asynchrously process data?

It seems to me that you are on the right track with executing `ProcessEvent` concurrently for each event. Only thing I would do is perhaps re-write the `foreach` loop to use `Enumerable.Select`, but that is a matter of flavor:

```
Inputs[] events = GetInputs();
var tasks = events.Select(ev => ProcessEvent(ev));
tempInputs = await Task.WhenAll<RegistrationInput>(tasks);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `ConcurentDictionary<ProcessEvent, byte>` and just use the `Keys`.
The usage of byte as type of `Value` is to minimize the amount of memory used. If you don't have any memory considerations you can use anything else.

It is thread safe and you can have all functionalities in `HashSet`